# Shopify HTML embedded video will not appear on iphones

Tags: html, video, shopify

Hi First post so please bare with me!

I have embedded an html video into my shopify homepage and all seems to be working until i try to view it on an Iphone.  It just displays a blank box where the video should be!

Here is my code

```
<video
 muted
 autoplay="autoplay" 
playsinline ="true" 
loop 
ref={videoRef} 
src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/0589c5d009374218bc6c47413835f6b1.mp4"  type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS seems fussy with regard to how the attributes are applied.  Try this:

```
<video src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/0589c5d009374218bc6c47413835f6b1.mp4" autoplay muted playsinline loop></video>
```